# How to explain this geometry problem to an 8th grader?

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, problem-solving

This is somehow embarrassing for me. So, I have been asked the following question (a similar one actually) by my friend who is currently an eight-grader:

> Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are known, find the length of $AI$.
>   [image]
>
> <sub>**Credit image:** [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incircle.html)</sub>

I'm able to tackle this problem using the cosine rule and the cosine double-angle formula. I obtained this result:
$$AI=r\sqrt{\frac{4bc}{2bc+a^2-b^2-c^2}}$$
but unfortunately, she hasn't been taught the cosine rule nor also trigonometry (sine, cosine, and tangent). I haven't figure it out using any 'simple methods'. Is it even possible? I guess I'm missing something obvious here. My question is how to deal with this problem using elementary ways preferably without using trigonometry? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does she know Heron's formula?

Comment: @Sawarnik Yes, she knows. I've also used that formula but there are 2 sides that we haven't known their lengths yet

Comment: Well, if we know Heron's then we can do by finding the length of the angle bisector, for which we will need Stewart's theorem. Is she aware of that? I am thinking of alternative ways though.

Comment: @Sawarnik She doesn't know Stewart's theorem.

Comment: Ah, why aren't we using $AI^2 = r^2 + (s-a)^2$!

Comment: @Sawarnik How do you get $AM_b=s-a$?

Comment: That comes from $AM_b = AM_c$ and so on. Let $AM_b = x$, $BM_c = y$, $CM_a = z$, then we have that $x + y + z = s$, and also $ y + z = BC$. Do you get it? :)

Comment: @Sawarnik OMG!! How stupid I am. Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you so much...

Comment: Done :) .. btw Anastasiya, it was nice to talk to you after a long long while :)

Comment: @Sawarnik It's also nice to have you respond my question. Thank you so much... :)

Comment: You're welcome! Also, please do be active on MSE at times .. love to see your awesome integrals and series :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that $AM_b = AM_c$ and so on, because lengths of tangents from a point to a circle are equal. So we let $AM_b=x, BM_c=y, CM_a=z$. Now,

$$AM_b + AM_c+ BM_a + BM_c + CM_b + CM_a = a+b+c$$
$$2(x+y+z)= a+b+c$$
$$x+y+z = s$$

We also know that $BC =  y+z$. Thus $ x = s - BC = s-a$. Now since $AI$ is the hypotenuse of right triangle $AIM_b$, we have:

$$AI^2= r^2 + (s-a)^2$$

Now using Heron's formula and $rs =\Delta$, we can represent $AI$ in terms of $a,b,c$ as:
$$AI = \sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s} + (s-a)^2}$$